# Graph Theory in Conway's Topograph

Tags: number-theory, soft-question, quadratic-forms

I'm wondering whether there is a lot of graph theory involved in the theory of Conway's topographs? I'm thinking about reading Conway's "The Sensual Quadratic Form" and I don't know if I should learn some graph theory before doing that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm readig that book right now. I think you can safely read this book without much knowledge of graph theory. Understanding the topograph requires very little knowledge of graph theory. Basically just definitions that you can easily google